# Using check boxes with a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, checkbox

I have an invoice with some lines. A line can only belong to one invoice. This is how my schema looks like:

```
create_table "invoices" do |t|
end

create_table "lines" do |t|
  t.integer  "invoice_id"
end
```

And my models:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

Now, when creating (or editing) an invoice I would like to show a list with all possible lines (the lines already exist in the database) and have a check box for each line to link it with the invoice.

I had a look at the HABTM problem but I don't think that's what I need here, the problem isn't as complex. I think the problem is me wanting to update the Unit#invoice_id while I am working on the invoice. Can I do this with a nested form or do I need a before_save callback here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A has_many association also adds the accessor `line_ids`, which you can create check boxes for.

If you're using `simple_form` or `formtastic` it's incredibly easy:

```
<%= f.input :line_ids, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

Which will create something like this:

```
<span>
  <input name="invoice[line_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
  <input checked="checked" class="check_boxes optional" id="invoice_line_ids_1" name="invoice[line_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label class="collection_check_boxes" for="invoice_line_ids_1">Line Name 1</label>
</span>

<span>
  <input name="invoice[line_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
  <input checked="checked" class="check_boxes optional" id="invoice_line_ids_2" name="invoice[line_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
  <label class="collection_check_boxes" for="invoice_line_ids_2">Line Name 2</label>
</span>
```

And that is all there is to it. No nested forms or anything else needed.

Comment: The annoying thing about this is the generated empty hidden field. It's useless, and it's interfering with the purpose of this helper (for associations). It will add an empty string '' to the array every time you submit it. Do any of you know how to go around it, but still use this helper?

Comment: maybe you can try - <%= f.input :line_ids, :as => :check_boxes include_blank => false %>

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at Iain's answer. It's definitely the right way to go but... I prefer not to use `simple_form` or `formtastic` for this example to keep it as simple as possible.

I used Iain's HTML output to extract the HTML I need. This snippet is the same as Iain's answer without the need of an extra library:

```
<% Line.all.each do |line| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "invoice[line_ids][]" %>
  <%= check_box_tag "invoice[line_ids][]", line.id, @invoice.lines.include?(line), :id => "invoice_line_ids_#{line.id}" %>
<% end %>
```

PS: The `Line.all` and `@invoice.lines...` should be extracted to the controller and invoice model, they don't belong in the view. They are only used for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using the [collection_check_boxes](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) helper method:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes :invoice, :lines, @lines, :id, :name %>
```

or Haml:

```
= collection_check_boxes :invoice, :lines, @lines, :id, :name
```