# has many through checkboxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have a many-many relationship with students and organizations. When creating a new student, I want to have a checkbox to select one or more organizations and save that. How do I do this? What does the MVC look like specifically? I can't find any online resource that gives me the whole overview.

***Updated code:***

in my form partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@student) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :organization_ids %><br />
    <%= collection_check_boxes :student, :organization_ids,       Organization.all, :id, :name %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button> <%= link_to   "Cancel", :back, {:class=>"btn btn-primary"} %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

controller:

```
def update
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  if Student.save_existing(params[:id], params[:student])
    flash[:notice] = "Student was successfully updated!"
    redirect_to students_path
  else
    flash[:error] = "Student failed to update."
    redirect_to students_path
  end
end

def student_params
   params.require(:student).permit(:name, :organization_ids => [])
end
```

student table:

```
create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
   t.integer  "organization_id"
   t.integer  "organization_ids"
end
```

my problem: when i do `@student.organization_ids.inspect`, it gives me an empty array meaning that the form didn't save my input form checkboxes

Comment: Can you update your post with model code.

Comment: This Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698952/using-check-boxes-with-a-has-many-relationship might help you

Comment: Is that the entire form code?

Comment: How does your update method look like? Can you post it?

Comment: no problem! just posted

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`collection_check_boxes`**](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes). Something like below in your ***student create form*** would do.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :organization_ids %><br />
    <%= collection_check_boxes(:student, :organization_ids, Organization.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

Comment: im getting undefined method organization_ids. any idea whats going on here? i have strong params set ".....".permit(....,:organization_ids => [])

Comment: @newto2rails Did you have `organization_ids` in your `students` table?

Comment: no I did not, thanks! just to make sure is this correct: add_column :students, :organization_ids, :integer

Comment: i have a new problem, the form doesnt save my organizations

Comment: @newto2rails You need to update your post with the code and explain the error in detail.